# Trying to use raycaster instead of the OnMouseOver() to display UI Text without sucess

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm a 3D artist, not a programmer so i need a little help. I'm trying to do a 360 virtual tour on Unity for Android.

I have almost everything working as needed. But i'm struggling to display info on some "hotspots" i created in the spheres (using sprites) and UI Text.

I'm using code from JONATHAN GONZALEZ at Xenosmash Games i found on youtube (thank you Jon). It works well for mouseover on PC, or even on Android. The problem is that on Android i must first touch somewhere on the screen to "spawn" the mouse cursor, and the other problem is that its not centered on the screen, it spawns where i touch (i need it to be at the center of the screen since i'm using gyro input to rotate the camera).

I need to change the code so that everything works without the initial tap on the screen.

So i tried to use raycaster instead of the mouse position, but without sucess.

Here is the code i'm using now (works with mouseover):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class displayUI: MonoBehaviour {

  public string myString;
  public Text myText;
  public float fadeTime;
  public bool displayInfo;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start() {
    myText.color = Color.clear;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
  }


  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update() {

    FadeText();

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
      Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
    }
  }

  void OnMouseOver() {
    displayInfo = true;
  }

  void OnMouseExit() {
    displayInfo = false;
  }

  void FadeText() {
    if (displayInfo) {
      myText.text = myString;
      myText.color = Color.Lerp(myText.color, Color.white, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
    } else {
      myText.color = Color.Lerp(myText.color, Color.clear, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
    }
  }

}
```

I would like to adapt it so it works with raycaster, displaying the UI text when the "center" of the screen points to the waypoint (sprite).

Thanks in advance!

Here is an attempt i did with raycaster without sucess:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class displayUI: MonoBehaviour {

  public string myString;
  public Text myText;
  public float fadeTime;
  public bool displayInfo;
  private bool hitSuccess = false;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start() {
    myText.color = Color.clear;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update() {
    FadeText();
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
      Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
    }
  }

  void OnMouseOver() {
    displayInfo = true;
  }

  void OnMouseExit() {
    displayInfo = false;
  }

  void FadeText() {
    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, 2)) {

      if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "AmbienteTrabalho") {
        hitSuccess = true;
      }

      if (hitSuccess) {
        myText.text = myString;
        myText.color = Color.Lerp(myText.color, Color.white, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
      }

    } else {
      myText.color = Color.Lerp(myText.color, Color.clear, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
    }

  }

}
```